# ISO 8859-1 Characters

Tags: json, iso-8859-1

I am working on an application in which we do translations for English/Spanish/French using a JSON file. I am a bit confused on if I need to use ISO 8859-1 Characters (their entity number) for the extra symbols on Spanish and French words. Everything is rendering properly (ex: é í ñ ¿)  but am I not sure if I am doing it incorrectly.

Ex. W/ ISO 8859-1 Characters  (these are using entity names, I heard using entity numbers are better?):

```
  "resultsperpage":"Resultados / P&aacute;gina",

  "customer":"Cliente",

  "corp":"Corporaci&oacute;n",

  "displaycorp":"MostrarCorporaci&oacute;n",
```

Ex. Without:

```
  "resultsperpage":"Resultados / Página",

  "customer":"Cliente",

  "corp":"Corporación",

  "displaycorp":"Mostrar Corporación",
```

Comment: JSON specification requires UTF-8. Why are you trying to send JSON as ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second approch.

Make absolutely sure you always use the same encoding when programmatically reading or writing to file, or when doing http.

Never rely on the default encoding of your system(s). Always specify your chosen encoding.

Make absolutely sure you always edit these files in the correct encoding.

The encoding itself does not matter. I recommed utf-8 over ISO 8859-1 or others.

Comment: great advice on making sure you edit the files in the correct encoding. Other team members had different utf settings and it caused so many headaches when the copy and pasted translations from excel.